# stripping file.html out of the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am writing a script that is suppose to illuminate different sections of the nav. each nav link is set up to be /directory/subdir/. It worked until I realized there needs to be more to this. if you are in a directory that is not the index file it doesn't work since it was directly matching HREF attribute. Now, how would I strip out the filename.html from the link and just get the directory? Thanks for all your help contributors!

Comment: `"/dir/subdir"` should work the same everywhere since it is an _absolute_ resource path. Do you mean that you have `"dir/subdir"` as the resource path (without the first slash)?

Comment: Well the thing is the nav doesn't have all its sub components listed.. ie "/dir/subdir/" will be listed but "/dir/subdir/subpage.html" so it can't match that attr. I think I might have to make it a substring

Comment: Can you give an example, on <http://jsfiddle.net> perhaps?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're asking. Can you give us some kind of example? Like ok jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com? Seriously people need to start using these when asking a question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dLBL5/ It works just fine if you're on any of those folders index.shtml files.. however, if you end up on another page the active class wont be there since it matches none of the a href attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /****** LINK DETECTION ******/


var nav = $('.mainNav a');
var loc = document.location.pathname;
var pathname = document.location.pathname.substring(1);
var parts = pathname.split(/\//);
var x = parts.length;
var hrefStr = "/"+parts[0]+"/"+parts[1]+"/";

switch (x) {
    case 2:
    $('.mainNav a').each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(this).attr('href') === loc) {
            var node = nav.eq(index).parent('li');
            var gpnode = node.parents('li');
            node.addClass('active');
            gpnode.addClass('active');
        }
    });
break;

default:

    $('.mainNav a').each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(this).attr('href') === hrefStr) {
            var node = nav.eq(index).parent('li');
            var gpnode = node.parents('li');
            node.addClass('active');
            gpnode.addClass('active');
        }
    });
}

/****** END LINK DETECTION ******/
```

Answer (score 1):

If i don't misunderstand, you're trying to hilight the your menu's link with

```
href="/dir/abc/"
```

while the page address is something like :

```
/dir/abc/index.shtml
/dir/abc/detail.shtml
/dir/abc/etc.shtml
```

right ? I've edited your code a bit. Hope this help :

```
var loc = document.location.pathname;
var nav = $('.mainNav a');

nav.each(function(index, element) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href') //-- edited
    if (loc.indexOf(href)==0) {     //-- edited
        var node = nav.eq(index).parent('li');
        var gpnode = node.parents('li');
        node.addClass('active');
        gpnode.addClass('active');

    }
});
```

Comment: Going to post the code I went with so this makes more sense, thank you for your reply